# Lightning Extension Not Showing Reminders When Opening Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, extension, lightning

When I first began using the Lightning calendar extension for TBird it used to show my reminders for events that were due each time I launched TBird if they were due to alarm. Even if I snoozed an event reminder it would pop up each time I opened Tbird regardless of how long I chose to snooze it. Also reminders for events are not popping up though they are supposed to when opening TBird on the same day of the event. There is a delay for some reason. I'll open T-Bird in the morning and if an event is due to remind me it may not do so until sometime later. In other words I want my events to pop up when I open T-Bird not later. So if say an event is due tomorrow I want the reminder to pop up when I open T-Bird first thing in the morning. I'm not getting the behavior I desire. This is how Lightning used to behave when I first started using it a few years back.

I'm hoping there is a fix or some way I can get Lightning to behave this way again. I haven't played with any setting in the config manager.

I've been ignoring this annoyance for probably close to two or three years. I'm currently using T-Bird 31.7.0 and Lightning 3.3.3. on Xubuntu 12.04. (EDIT 14.04) If anyone has any ideas I would be most grateful.

Comment: Version 4 beta was released on 5 June 2015 so I believe the project is still active.

Comment: I can confirm that this is not happening on my systems running Xubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.  Are you correctly setting the reminders when adding a calender event? Perhaps upgrade to 14.04?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am running 14.04.  My Bad... I edited the above. Sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand the question but in about config there is 2 settings for snooze /edit/preferences/advanced/about:config

```
`mail.spam.markAsNotJunkMarksUnRead;true

 calendar.alarms.defaultsnoozelength;5
```

and when you add or edit an event or task hit the reminder buttom and set the alarm.
hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply! These lines were already set to the values you suggest. And the events I have written about do have alarms. Being that my calendar is so many years old I'm thinking about backing up  ~..thunderbird, delete the one in ~ and  and try a fresh install of lightning. and see if that works..